# alternative code for createCriteria() method in Hibernate 5.2.2

Tags: hibernate

In Hibernate 5.2.2 createCriteria() method is deprecated. Please give the alternative solution and code snippet.

Code

```
Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Student3.class);   
List<Student3> studentsNameList= criteria.list();           

        for (Student3 studentName : studentsNameList) {
            System.out.println("Student details - "+studentName.getName()+" -- "+studentName.getEmail());   }
```

Searching in google I found that `DetachedCriteria`  can be used instead of `createCriteria()` but it does not have a list() method

```
DetachedCriteria detachedCriteria=DetachedCriteria.forClass(Student3.class);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just got done fighting the same thing. The Hibernate documentation says to use JPA Criteria. Here is what I came up with...

```
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;

CriteriaQuery<Student3> cq = session.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(Student3.class);
cq.from(Student3.class);
List<Student3> studentsNameList = session.createQuery(cq).getResultList();

for (Student3 studentName : studentsNameList) {
    System.out.println("Student details - "+studentName.getName()+" -- "+studentName.getEmail());   
}
```

Not as elegant, but typed.

--Update--
I have not dove too far into the details yet, but here is how I would go about adding an actual criteria:

```
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Student3> cq = cb.createQuery(Student3.class);

Root<Student3> studentRoot = cq.from(Student3.class);
ParameterExpression<Integer> id = cb.parameter(Integer.class);

cq.select(studentRoot).where(cb.eq(studentRoot.get("id"),id));

 TypedQuery<Student3> query = em.createQuery(cq);
 query.setParameter(p, 2);
 List<Student3> results = query.getResultList();
```

Again, I am just learning JPA so there may be an easier way (and I would love to know about it if you find something)

Comment: The code is showing errors-The type CriteriaQuery is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Student3>.

Comment: Be sure you are importing: `import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery` and not `import org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaQuery`

Comment: Thanks now its working. Can you help me to add Restrictrictions and set Projections in this code.Earlier it was easy like-criteria.add(Restrictions.gt("id",2));criteria=criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("email"));